# Drawing based on MouseEvent in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to draw a rect on frame based on Mouse event, the problem is that I can't do it when I got a video steaming, the program crashes  here is my code :

```
  cv::Rect theBox;
   bool drawing_box = false;

  void draw_box(Mat* frame, cv::Rect rectangle){
cvRectangle( frame, cvPoint(theBox.x, theBox.y), cvPoint   heBox.x+theBox.width,theBox.y+theBox.height),
            cvScalar(0xff,0x00,0x00) );
```

}
void mouse(int event, int x, int  y ,int flags, void* parameter){

```
Mat* image = (Mat*) parameter;

switch( event ){
    case CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE: 
        if( drawing_box ){
            theBox.width = x-theBox.x;
            theBox.height = y-theBox.y;
        }
        break;

    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing_box = true;
        theBox = cvRect( x, y, 0, 0 );
        break;

    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing_box = false;
        if( theBox.width < 0 ){
            theBox.x += theBox.width;
            theBox.width *= -1;
        }
        if( theBox.height < 0 ){
            theBox.y += theBox.height;
            theBox.height *= -1;
        }
        draw_box( image, theBox );
        //cv::rectangle(parameter, theBox, CV_RGB(255,0,0));
        break;
}
```

}

```
int  main(){

    cv::Mat frame;
    int key = 0 ;
    const char* name = "box";
    theBox = Rect(-1,-1,0,0);
    cv::VideoCapture cap(1);

    if (!cap.isOpened()){
        cout<< " capture isn't open " << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::namedWindow(name);

    while (key != 27){

        cap >> frame;
        cv::imshow(name,frame);
        cv::setMouseCallback(name,mouse,&frame);

        key = cv::waitKey(1);
    }

    cv::destroyAllWindows();

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When video streaming is taking place the display is getting updated...and at the same time trying to draw a rectangle is difficult...since the rectangle is to be drawn on the basis of inputs of the mouse movement and mouse movement is independent of the streaming video frames...hence the rectangle might get overwritten (should not crash though). You can try to draw a transparent (size based on mouse move event..) screen over your video frames in each iteration of your video frame display...